# Error en Angular con dev-server

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript, angular15

voy iniciando en Angular con un proyecto de mi trabajo. Después de actualizar de angular 11 a angular 15 me presenta el siguiente error. Si alguien me puede apoyar, ser los agradecería.

```
C:\Proyectos\SIT_V23\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\hostReportError.js:4
    setTimeout(function () { throw err; }, 0);
                             ^

Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import 'C:\Proyectos\SIT_V23\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from C:\Proyectos\SIT_V23\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
Did you mean to import C:/Proyectos/SIT_V23/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/dev-server/index.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:319:17)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:945:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:525:22)
    at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1186:29)
    at importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:429:21)
    at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/vm:106:46)
    at importModuleDynamicallyCallback (node:internal/process/esm_loader:35:14)
    at eval (eval at loadEsmModule (C:\Proyectos\SIT_V23\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:199:12), <anonymous>:3:1)
    at loadEsmModule (C:\Proyectos\SIT_V23\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:199:68)
    at getBuilder (C:\Proyectos\SIT_V23\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:222:35)
    at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.loadBuilder (C:\Proyectos\SIT_V23\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:174:31) {
  code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT',
  url: 'file:///C:/Proyectos/SIT_V23/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/dev-server'
}
```

Comment: Eso podría ser cualquier cosa. Vuelve a hacer la migración pero una versión mayor a la vez y revisa en cada una si sigue funcionando. Es más fácil así encontrar los problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia las versiones en **package.json** y checa la versión del Angular CLI.

Específicamente el error dice que tienes problemas con
`@angular-devkit/build-angular` entonces es probable que tengas todavía la versión 11, después de cambiarlo haces un `npm install` y debería de resolverse.